# Outlook finding emails I'm not looking for

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, google-workspace

My Outlook is finding more emails than it should find, given the search query.

If I search for "orange" I find all emails that contain the word "orange". If I search for "grlkjehgpoiureohgiaeurogaie" I find **all** my emails. There should be no results, but Outlook 2013 shows **all my emails**.

I'm using Outlook 2013 in combination with Google App Sync on Windows 10.

Things I've tried:

- Rebuilding the search index
- sfc -scannow (no problems)

If I use advanced search, it does work as expected. (Returning no results).

How can I tell Outlook not to show results if it doesn't find anything?